# Factory_Girl explanation using has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I was wondering if could anyone explain the evaluator part of the following factory using a has_many, i think i have an understanding but am not sure if i fully understand where my images are going sohow i can run a custom validation method against them later on in a rspec test

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :animal, class: Animal do
  name 'test'

   ignore do
    images_count 1
   end


  after(:create) do |animal, evaluator|
   create_list(:animal_image, evaluator.images_count, animal: animal)
  end
 end 
end

FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :animal_image do
  image { File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/yp2.jpg") }
 end 
end
```

So if i run this command

```
animal = FactoryGirl.create(:animal, images_count: 4)
ap(animal)

 :id => 95,
 :animal_type => nil,
 :name => nil,
 :description => nil,
 :age => nil,
 :size => nil,
 :gender => nil,
 :spay_neuter => nil,
 :chipped => nil,
 :child_friendly => nil,
 :reference => nil,
 :dog_breed_id => nil,
 :user_id => nil,
 :created_at => Wed, 15 Oct 2014 08:56:56 UTC +00:00,
 :updated_at => Wed, 15 Oct 2014 08:56:56 UTC +00:00,
 :cat_breed_id => nil
}
# Not worried about nil entries as didn't pass anything to populate them
```

This will create my animal object and after it will create 4 instances of :animal_image, however when i then try to create my animal_images using my created animal object the images are not there

```
animal_image = AnimalImage.create(animal: animal)
ap(animal_image)

:id => nil,
:animal_id => 96,
:image => #<AnimalImageUploader:0x00000002e00478 @model=#<AnimalImage id: nil, animal_id: 96, image: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @mounted_as=:image>,
:created_at => nil,
:updated_at => nil
}
```

As you can see the id is there but not my images

Does anyone have any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Also as per comments i have checked the errors

```
@base=#<AnimalImage id: nil, animal_id: 96, image: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:base=>["Please add an image"]}>
```

and this is my AnimalImage Setup

```
class AnimalImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, AnimalImageUploader
  belongs_to :animal

  validate :limit_num_of_images
  validate :image_size_validation, :if => "image?"

  def limit_num_of_images
   if image.size < 1
     errors.add(:base, "Please add an image")
   end
  end

  def image_size_validation
    if image.size > 1.megabytes
     errors.add(:base, "Image's should be less than 1MB")
    end
 end    
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Check `animal_image.errors`

Comment: updated question with output

Comment: not sure to understand but you are not using the factory when creating your `animal_image`. Simply do `animal = FactoryGirl.create(:animal)` and then `animal.animal_images` will be full with your 5 (by default) animal images.

Comment: @Richlewis - Thanks. Could you show your AnimalImage model as well?

Comment: @BroiSatse the whole thing or just the association setup ?

Comment: Mainly validation stuff - model is not saved because those are failing. Are you using paperclip for image uploads?

Comment: @BroiSatse updated, using carrierwave for image upload (s3 bucket), but storing locally in test environment

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois thanks, I have now found my animal_images using the way you mentioned, maybe i misunderstood how factory_girl builds the associated object.. would you like to add that as an answer, with an explanation of what i done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FactoryGirl will build the associated objects for you when using `create_list`.

Simply create a new animal:

```
animal = FactoryGirl.create(:animal)
```

and then iterate on its images:

```
animal.animal_images
```

You should have 5 images by default (as specified in the `ignore` attribute). You can control the number of images like so:

```
animal = FactoryGirl.create(:animal, images_count: 10)
animal.animal_images.count
 => 10
```